# Encoding directed graph as numbers

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let's say that I have a directed graph, with a single root and without cycles. I would like to add a type on each node (for example as an integer with some custom ordering) with the following property:

```
if Node1.type <= Node2.type then there exists a path from Node1 to Node2
```

Note that topological sorting actually satisfies the reversed property:

```
if there exists a path from Node1 to Node2 then Node1.type <= Node2.type
```

so it cannot be used here.

Now note that integers with natural ordering cannot be used here because every 2 integers can be compared, i.e. the ordering of integers is linear while the tree does not have to be.

So here's an example. Assume that the graph has 4 nodes `A, B, C, D` and 4 arrows:

```
A->B, A->C, B->D, C->D
```

So it's a diamond. Now we can put

```
A.type = 00
B.type = 01
C.type = 10
D.type = 11
```

where on the right side we have integers in binary format. The comparison is defined bitwise:

```
(X <= Y) if and only if (n-th bit of X <= n-th bit of Y for all n)
```

So I guess such ordering could be used, the question is how to construct values from a given graph? I'm not even sure if the solution always exists. Any hints?

**UPDATE:** Since there is some misunderstanding about terminology I'm using let me be more explicite: I'm interested in directed acyclic graph such that there is exactly one node without predecessors (a.k.a. the root) and there's at most one arrow between any two nodes. The diamond would be an example. It **does not** have to have one leaf (i.e. the node without successors). Each node might have multiple predecessors and multiple successors. You might say that this is a partially ordered set with a smallest element (i.e. a unique globally minimal element).

Comment: If `Node1.type <= Node2.type` never holds then the requirement is trivially met.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure I understand, care to elaborate?

Comment: If `a < b then there's a path from a to b`. If `a < b` is false then the whole statement is true.

Comment: Wait, do you have a tree or a DAG?

Comment: @n.m. Seems like a DAG, not a tree. I think he meant "tree-like" directed graph, which is indeed a DAG.

Comment: @n.m. `then the whole statement is true` What you mean is that you can't deduce whether there is a path if `!a<b`? I understand that. It would be perfect to have `if and only if` relation but it is not necessary for me.

Comment: @n.m. What's a difference between DAG and a tree?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph

Comment: @n.m. So the difference is that a tree is not directed? Then I'm interested in DAG.

Comment: No, the difference is not that a tree is not directed -- a tree can be directed or not, and an undirected tree can always be "made" (or considered) directed by choosing an arbitrary root vertex and directing all edges "away" from it.  The difference is that in a directed tree, every vertex except the root has *exactly one* in-edge, while a vertex in a DAG may have an arbitrary number of in-edges.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Ok, so the terminology I'm using might not be 100% correct but I am interested in directed acyclic graph such that there is at most 1 arrow between any two nodes and there is exactly one node without predecessors. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any DAG, you can *define* `x <= y` as "there's a path from x to y". This relation is a partial order. I take it that the question is how to represent this relation efficiently.

For each vertex X, define ¡X to be the set of vertices reachable from X (including X itself). The two statements

- ¡X is a subset of ¡Y
- X is reachable from Y

are equivalent.

Encode these sets as bitsets (N-bit binary numbers), and you are set.

Comment: I'm actually surprised how simple that is. The two equivalent statements was what I didn't see. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You call the relation `<=`, but it's necessarily not complete (that is: it may be that for a given pair `a` and `b`, neither `a <= b` nor `b <= a`).

Here's one idea for how to define it.

If your nodes are numbered 0, 1..., N-1, then you can define `type` like this:

```
type(i) = (1 << i) + sum(1 << (N + j), for j such that Path(i, j))
```

And define `<=` like this:

```
type1 <= type2 if (type1 >> N) & type2 != 0
```

That is, `type(i)` encodes the value of `i` in the lowest `N` bits, and the set of all reachable nodes in the highest `N` bits. The `<=` relation looks for the target node in the encoded set of reachable nodes.

This definition works whether or not there's cycles in the graph, and in fact just encodes an arbitrary relation on your set of nodes.

You could make the definition a little more efficient by using `ceil(log2(N))` bits to encode the node number (for a total of `N + ceil(log2(N))` bits per `type`).

Comment: ":it's necessarily not transitive" Why? If there's a path from A to B, and a path from B to C, then there's a path from A to C.

Comment: @n.m. That means that `there exists a path` relation is transitive. Not the `<=` relation. Theoretically it is possible that `<=` is not transitive even though it maps into a transitive relation. Note that I do not require that `<=` has to hold if a path exists. Requiring from `<=` to be transitive would be nice, indeed, but I don't think it's necessary for my purposes.

Comment: Uh, yes it's transitive. But it's not complete. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @PaulHankin Actually this property is known as [totality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation). This is not a requirement for `<=` to be a [partial ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). I like your idea, I will give it a try soon.

Comment: Ok, so while this is an interesting approach I find it quite difficult to actually understand what's going on here. But thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**The question said (and continues to say) that the input is a tree, but a later edit contradicted this with an example of a diamond graph.  In such non-tree cases, my algorithm below won't apply.**

The existing answers work for general relations on general directed graphs, which inflates their representation sizes to O(n) bits for n vertices.  Since you have a tree, a shorter O(log n)-bit representation is possible.

In a tree directed away from the root, for any two vertices u and v, the sets of leaves L(u) and L(v) reachable from u and v, respectively, must either be disjoint, or one must be a subset of the other.  If they are disjoint, then u is not reachable from v (and vice versa); if one is a proper subset of the other, the one with the smaller set is reachable from the other (and in this case, the one with the smaller set will necessarily have strictly greater depth).  If L(u) = L(v), then u is reachable from v if and only if depth(v) < depth(u), where depth(u) is the number of edges on the path from the root to u.  (In particular, if L(u) = L(v) and depth(u) = depth(v), then u = v.)

We can encode this relationship concisely by noticing that all leaves reachable from a given vertex v occupy a contiguous segment of the leaves output by an inorder traversal of the tree.  For any given vertex v, this set of leaves can therefore be represented by a pair of integers `(first, last)`, with `first` identifying the first leaf (in inorder traversal order) and `last` the last.  The test for whether a path exists from i to j is then very simple -- in pseudo-C++:

```
bool doesPathExist(int i, int j) {
    return x[i].first <= x[j].first && x[i].last >= x[j].last && depth[i] <= depth[j];
}
```

Note that if every non-leaf vertex in the tree has at least 2 children, then you don't need to bother with depths, since L(u) = L(v) implies u = v in this case.  (My original version of the post made this assumption; I've now fixed it to work even when this is not the case.)

Comment: "_must either be disjoint, or one must be a subset of the other_": this is not true in a DAG.  In particular, a node may have two ingoing edges coming from different "subtrees". The diamond example given by the OP is an instance of that case.

Comment: @PatriceGahide: First line of OP's question: "Let's say that I have a directed graph, **actually a tree**"

Comment: See the comments of the OP. We're dealing with DAGs.

Comment: @PatriceGahide: The comments of the OP indicate that s/he's very confused about what s/he's dealing with.

Comment: Maybe, but the sample instance (diamond) makes it pretty clear that you cannot assume what I pointed in my original comment.

Comment: @PatriceGahide: You're right, I was working off an earlier version which didn't have this example.  I'll add a warning... and downvote this question :(

Comment: @j_random_hacker I am not confused about what I'm dealing with. At most I might not know the proper terminology, however the example I gave should be sufficient. So if that solution doesn't work in diamond case then I can't make use of it.

Comment: @freakish: You've edited your question, but it still contains "Let's say that I have a directed graph, actually a tree" at the top -- the sentence that caused me to waste my time on an answer that doesn't solve your problem.  *Please* remove this.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Dude, I'm not going to remove anything. The question should be perfectly clear now. I'm sorry that you misunderstood me. But I assure you that I've wasted lots of time here on SO as well. Don't make a big deal out of it, seriously. Besides your answer can still be helpful to some other people.